# How do a for-each in this xsl?

Tags: xslt, jdeveloper, bpel

I get this result from a service in a Bpel process.
How I do a For-each with OSTypeOutput and inside of it
test the value of "serv"?

I'am trying to do a transformation.

```
<siOutPut>
  -<OOPreOutput xmlns="http://my.web.com/test/types">
    -<OSTypes xmlns:ns1="http://my.web.com/test/servtp">
        -<ns1:OSTypeOutput>
            <ns1:serv>A1</ns1:serv>
            <ns1:serv>A2</ns1:serv>
            <ns1:serv>A3</ns1:serv>
        </ns1:OSTypeOutput>
    </OSTypes>
  </OOPreOutput>
</siOutPut>
```

I have tried this way but I can't get nothing:

```
  <xsl:param name="Param">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">A3</xsl:text>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns1:GetTestResponse>
     <ns1:MyId>
       <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:OOPreOutput/ns1:OSTypes/ns1:OSTypeOutput">
         <xsl:if test="(./serv = $Param)">
           <xsl:value-of select="'Found'"/>
         </xsl:if>  
       </xsl:for-each>
     </ns1:MyId>      
    </ns1:GetTestResponse>
  </xsl:template>
```

I've made this test:

```
<ns1:MyId>
  <xsl:for-each select="/ns1:OOPreOutput/ns1:OSTypes">
       <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
</ns1:MyId>
```

And get this result :
A1A2A3

I also did this test but without result :

```
  <xsl:param name="Param">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">A3</xsl:text>
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns1:GetTestResponse>
     <ns1:MyId>
       <xsl:if test="/ns1:OOPreOutput/ns1:OSTypes/ns1:OSTypeOutput/ns1:serv = $Param">
           <xsl:value-of select="'Found'"/>
       </xsl:if>  
     </ns1:MyId>      
    </ns1:GetTestResponse>
  </xsl:template>
```

I changed a little bit the output:

```
-<siOutPut>
  -<OOPreOutput xmlns="http://int.clear.com/types">
    +<Deliv></Deliv>
    <OSTypes>
    <ns1:serv xmlns:ns1="http://my.test.com/web/services">A1</ns1:serv>
    <ns1:serv xmlns:ns1="http://my.test.com/web/services">A2</ns1:serv>
    <ns1:serv xmlns:ns1="http://my.test.com/web/services">A3</ns1:serv>
    </OSTypes>
  </OOPreOutput>
</siOutPut>
```

How I should verify if ns1:serv has "A3" value?

Comment: identify the programming language please

Comment: This transformation is done in a Oracle BPel process with JDev. I don't use any other language to do it.

Comment: `select="/ns1:OOPreOutput/ns1:OSTypes"` won't work because `ns1:OOPreOutput` isn't the root node of that XML (there's an `siOutput` above it)

Comment: Do I specify the RootNode like this :/ns1:siOutput/ns1:OOPreOutput/ns1:OSTypes/ns1:OSTypeOutput

Answer (score 1):

You don't have one of the namespaces declared in the stylesheet. Re-writing the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://my.web.com/test/servtp" xmlns:ns2="http://my.web.com/test/types" version="1.0">

<xsl:param name="Param">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">A3</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ns1:GetTestResponse>
        <ns1:MyId>
            <xsl:for-each select="/siOutPut/ns2:OOPreOutput/ns2:OSTypes/ns1:OSTypeOutput">
                <xsl:if test="(./ns1:serv = $Param)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Found'"/>
                </xsl:if>  
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ns1:MyId>      
    </ns1:GetTestResponse>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, there is no need for doing a for-each as your just want to check the existence of "serv" with some value.
It can be done this way too:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns1:GetTestResponse>
    <ns1:MyId>
            <xsl:if test="siOutPut/ns2:OOPreOutput/ns2:OSTypes/ns1:OSTypeOutput/ns1:serv = $Param">
                <xsl:value-of select="'Found'"/>
            </xsl:if>  
    </ns1:MyId>      
</ns1:GetTestResponse>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I have the namespace declared. I've tried second suggestion and it did not get the 'Found'.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to simplify the logic by using apply templates. I think the problem may be < xsl:value-of select="'Found'"/>. I'd say it's < xsl:text>'Found'< /xsl:text>. And I think you didn't match < siOutPut>. I don't think < xsl:template match="/"> solves it.

```
<xsl:param name="Param">
 <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">A3</xsl:text>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
 <ns1:GetTestResponse>
  <ns1:MyId>
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </ns1:MyId>      
 </ns1:GetTestResponse>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1:OSTypeOutput">
   <xsl:for-each select="ns1:serv">
     <xsl:if test=".= $Param">
       <xsl:text>'Found'</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>  
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

After changing the output I made this for-each and it Worked:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/ns2:OOPreOutput/ns2:OSTypes">
    <xsl:if test="(./ns1:serv = $Param)">
         <xsl:value-of select="'Found'"/>
    </xsl:if>  
</xsl:for-each>
```

And also doing the Direct test as suggested Lingamurthy

```
<xsl:if test="ns2:OOPreOutput/ns2:OSTypes/ns1:serv = $Param">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Found'"/>
<xsl:if>
```

Thank you all.